# Alternates to quotation marks in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string, quotes, quotation-marks

I have this line of code in a method:

```
system("osascript -e 'tell app "System Events" to restart'");
```

As you can see, I've got two quotation marks, and since these terminal commands have to be so specific, I need to know another way to run a system command from ObjC. I've already tried using  `''`  and the `/` method but that didn't work out.

Comment: Use escapes just like you did in C or Java.  (You do already know C or Java don't you?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to "escape" the quote characters to tell the compiler that the should be part of the string rather than delimiters of the string. You say you "tried using … the / method", but you got the wrong character. You escape characters using the backslash, not the forward slash:

```
-(IBAction)reboot:(id)sender{
    system("osascript -e 'tell app \"System Events\" to restart'");
}
```

Comment: thanks, ill try that with my other actions too

Comment: @Wafflepi That is just plain "C", it really pays to study a good "C" book.